# Subtract 24hrs in T-SQL from Today's Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to Subtract 24hrs in T-SQL from Today's Date

Thanks!

Comment: I think I figured it out Select DATEADD(HOUR,-24, GETDATE())

Answer (score 14):

```
 SELECT GETDATE() - 1
```

The `-1` substracts one day from current date (`GETDATE()`)

Comment: works - but seems a bit unintuitive; to me, it's not obvious right from the get go that the -1 is "-1 day" .... I'd rather be explicit `(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())` - makes it easier to read (for others, and for you in a year or two) and helps with maintenance...

Comment: well, if you use it all the time, than you won't forget, but in general, I have to agree with you

Comment: This subtracts 1 day. NOT 24 hours. Huge difference.

Comment: @Kyle: How is it different exactly? Some example maybe?

Answer (score 10):

```
DECLARE @Now datetime, @Calc datetime

SET @Now = GetDate()
SET @Calc = DateAdd(hh, -24, @Now)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select dateadd(d,-1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Sorry kind of new posting on this site.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()) AS yesterday
```